# VB6 vs VB.NET naming restrictions for winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 user control with text boxes named txtIndexData(0), txtIndexData(1), txtIndexData(2), etc.
The code for the user control uses for loops and an incrementing counter to do things to each of the text boxes (or a specific number text box) with code like the following:

```
        ' Check each of the text boxes to see if
        ' any are currently editing a text constant.  If
        ' so, go back to the previous scroll setting
        ' and allow the text box to finish before scrolling
        For I = 0 To LINK_BOX_SIZE - 1
        If txtIndexData(I).Locked = False Then
                CurrentScrollValue = vsbIndex.Value
                vsbIndex.Value = LastScrollValue
                Call txtIndexData_LostFocus(I)
                vsbIndex.Value = CurrentScrollValue
            End If
        Next I
```

When trying to replicate this in VB.Net, txtIndexData(1) is apparently an invalid identifier for a textbox (because of the parentheses I guess). How should I name these so that I can write functions that affect certain text boxes based on a variable (like I above) inserted into the name?

Sorry for my lack of VB6/VB.NET/WinForms knowledge. I understand I might be missing something here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately control arrays are not supported in .Net, like they were in VB6 (I do miss them). What you have to do now is put them into an array/list/collection yourself (code behind) or put them inside a single container, like a panel, then iterate through the `controls` collection of the panel.

Comment: @Steve thanks! Just having control array to google lets me understand what's happening here. I was a little lost. I'll now look into how to do what you said.

Comment: There is a VB6 Compatibility layer/assembly which does allow Control arrays, but you are much better off without them and there is nothing unfortunate about it.

Comment: You may want to look at the [DataRepeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.itemtemplate(v=vs.120).aspx). This allows your form to display an arbitrary number of controls in a repeated layout, by adding a control such as a textbox to the repeater's ItemTemplate, as shown in the example in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something like this in .Net because I also learned vb6 first before .Net :)

`txtIndexData1`, `txtIndexData2` ..... as the names of the controls.
Now the loop will look like this ***[Assumed the textbox controls are dropped on the form directly]***

```
For I = 0 To LINK_BOX_SIZE - 1
        Dim obj As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("txtIndexData" & I), TextBox)
        If obj.ReadOnly = False Then
            CurrentScrollValue = vsbIndex.Value
            vsbIndex.Value = LastScrollValue
            Call txtIndexData1_LostFocus(obj, New System.EventArgs())
            vsbIndex.Value = CurrentScrollValue
        End If
Next I
```

The only pain there is naming the controls yourself as vb6 will increment the index automatically, but there is also a solution for that. Just create a usercontrol and change the inheritance to textbox directly, then name the control `txtIndexData`. Now compile your program. It should appear on the toolbox. Drag it onto your project. When you create a duplicate of it, it will increment automatically to `txtIndexData1`, `txtIndexData2`, `txtIndexData3` ... and so on.